# Error on a KeyValueStore Interface

Tags: java

I got a error in the `<Map<String,byte[]>> pairs` line  but i can't figure it out why. Please help.

```
public interface KeyValueStore {

         public void put(String key, byte[] value);
         public byte[] get(String key);

         public void putAll(<Map<String,byte[]>> pairs);
         public Map<String,byte[]> getAll(Collection<String> keys);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That < before Map should go away, as well as its matching >.